# MPI scatter is not working for large array size

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am trying to scatter a few 1D arrays in different processors. When the number of elements of the 1D array is small, the code works fine.
The code is as:

```
program main
  
  use mpi_f08
  implicit none
  integer i,ni,nj,images,ierr,mpisize,mpirank, tmp_tmp,num_target_total
  integer,dimension (128) :: iseed
  real diff,norm
  real temp_x, temp_y, temp_z, temp1, temp2, temp3
  integer ni_t, nj_t
  real(8),parameter :: pi=3.14159265358979312d0
  real(8),allocatable,dimension(:) :: xi,ui,ud,xj,gj
  real(8),allocatable,dimension(:) :: xi_t_x, xi_t_y, xi_t_z
  real(8),allocatable,dimension(:) :: ui_t_x, ui_t_y, ui_t_z
  real(8),allocatable,dimension(:) :: xj_t_x, xj_t_y, xj_t_z
  real(8),allocatable,dimension(:) :: gj_t_x, gj_t_y, gj_t_z
  real(8),allocatable,dimension(:) :: temp_xi, temp_yi, temp_zi
  real(8),allocatable,dimension(:) :: temp_xj, temp_yj, temp_zj
  real(8),allocatable,dimension(:) :: temp_gj_x, temp_gj_y, temp_gj_z
  real(8),allocatable,dimension(:) :: temp_ux, temp_uy, temp_uz
  
  !#####################################################################!
print*, 'here1'
  ni_t = 10
  nj_t = 50000
  allocate(xi_t_x(ni_t))
  allocate(xj_t_x(nj_t))
  do i = 1,128
     iseed(i) = 0
  enddo
  call random_seed(put=iseed)
  call random_number(xi_t_x)
  call random_number(xj_t_x)
print*, 'here2'
  do i = 1,nj_t
     xj_t_x(i) = 5*(xj_t_x(i) - 0.5) * pi
  enddo
  do i = 1,ni_t
     xi_t_x(i) = 3*(xi_t_x(i) - 0.5) * pi
  enddo
    print*, 'here3'
  !#####################################################################!
  
  call mpi_init(ierr)
  call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world,mpisize,ierr)
  call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world,mpirank,ierr)
  !#####################################################################!
    print*, 'here4'
  if(mpirank .ne. 0) then
    ni = int(ni_t/mpisize)
    nj = int(nj_t/mpisize)
    allocate( xi(3*ni),ui(3*ni),xj(3*nj),gj(3*nj))
    allocate( temp_xi(ni))
    allocate( temp_xj(nj))
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierr)
    print*, 'here6', ni, nj, mpirank
    call mpi_scatter(xi_t_x, ni, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, temp_xi, ni, &
        MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, mpirank, mpi_comm_world, IERR)

    call mpi_scatter(xj_t_x, nj, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, temp_xj, nj, &
        MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, mpirank, mpi_comm_world, IERR)
    print*, 'here7', mpirank

  else 
    ni = int(ni_t/mpisize) + mod(ni_t,mpisize)
    nj = int(nj_t/mpisize) + mod(nj_t,mpisize)
    allocate( xi(3*ni),ui(3*ni),xj(3*nj),gj(3*nj))
    allocate( temp_xi(ni))
    allocate( temp_xj(nj))
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierr)
    print*, 'here6', ni, nj, mpirank
    call mpi_scatter(xi_t_x, ni, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, temp_xi, ni, &
        MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, mpirank, mpi_comm_world, IERR)
    
    call mpi_scatter(xj_t_x, nj, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, temp_xj, nj, &
        MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, mpirank, mpi_comm_world, IERR)
  endif
  call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierr)
print*, 'here5', mpirank
  !#####################################################################!

  do i = 1,nj
     xj(3*i-2) = temp_xj(i)
  enddo
  do i = 1,ni
     xi(3*i-2) = temp_xi(i)
  enddo
print*, 'here5', mpirank

  deallocate( xi,ui,xj,gj )
  call mpi_finalize(ierr)
print*, 'here10', mpirank
end program main
```

The compilation:

```
[bidesh@anode0 wrapper]$ mpif90 -ggdb test_R2.f90 
[bidesh@anode0 wrapper]$
```

And I run with mpirun -np 10 ./a.out
When ni_t = 5000, the code runs fine.

```
...
 here5           4
 here7           4
 here10           0
 here10           5
 here10           8
 here10           2
 here10           4
 here10           1
 here10           6
 here10           7
 here10           3
 here10           9
```

But when ni_t = 50000, the code is stuck.

```
...
 here4
 here4
 here6           1        5000           4
 here6           1        5000           0
 here4
 here6           1        5000           2
 here4
 here6           1        5000           3
 here4
 here6           1        5000           5
 here4
 here6           1        5000           6
 here4
 here6           1        5000           8
 here4
 here6           1        5000           7
 here4
 here6           1        5000           1
 here6           1        5000           9
```

I am not understanding the error I am making. If anyone can help me to understand my error, I will be really helped.
I am from mechanical background. If I do not understand something which may be very obvious kindly pardon me.
Thank you.

Comment: Wlcome, please take the Welcome [tour]. I highly suggest using `use mpi` instead og `include 'mpif.h'`. This will enable the compiler to diagnose many kinds of errors when calling the MPI procedures incorrectly. Be aware that `real(8)` is non-portable and may not coincide with MPI_DOUBLE or may not exist at all (but it is not the cause of your current problem).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I changed it to use mpi. It suggested me to change mpi_double to Mpi_double_precision, and I changed real(8) to real. But still, the problem exists when the number of elements in the array is large. Am I doing something wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: please edit your question with the updated code that freezes so it can be reproduced.

Comment: Using just `real` is probably not what you want here. if you do not want to bother eith kind constants either use `double precision` or keep `real(8)` but remember it is better to modernize it in future.

Comment: @BideshSengupta - what you have described is almost certainly wrong, real does not map onto mpi_double_precision. As Gilles asks please update the code. Also please shows up the compile line you are using.

Comment: At first glance (in a hurry) it looks as though you want different recv sizes on proc 0 compared to all the other procs, see how `ni `and `nj` are set. This is not what mpi_scatter does, all messages are the same size. Is this what you want ot is it just a typo? Could you also please show us exactly how you run the code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks all for your answers. I updated the code. @IanBush I wish to send all the remaining portions of the array in the root.

Comment: mpi_scatter sends the same amount of data to each process. If the size of the array is *not* a multiple of the number of the processes each one might want a different amount of data as the array does not divide up evenly. Therefore you can't use mpi_scatter. You probably want mpi_scatterv.

Comment: In the updated code the root argument to mpi_scatter is wrong in all cases, it should be simply 0 . Fix these and I think it should work when the size of the arrays are an exact multiple of the number of processes used - but no time to test now. Will try to find time to write an answer later.

Comment: @IanBush Yes, you are correct. The root was the problem. Anyway, I have to use scatterv. Thanks a lot.